# Get Consumer key and Signature from Pump.io server

Tags: node.js, api, postman, node.js-stream, activity-streams

how can I get the consumer key, Signature and consumer secret(dynamically) from the server(OAuth1). So, that I can pass it in Headers->Authorization to execute my routes(register) in Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get consumer key and Signature by registering client by making `POST` request at `{{url}}/api/client/register`

Sent the following code in the Body:

```
{
  "type": "client_associate",
  "application_name": "Your Application Name",
  "application_type": "web" 
}
```